# Yiistrap configuration issue

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions

I am trying to get Yiistrap (Bootstrap for the Yii Framework) to work on Cent OS 6.5. I've unpacked the yiistrap-master into extensions/bootstrap and added the following to protected/config/main.php:

```
// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    'aliases'=>array(
    'bootstrap'=>'/var/www/html/happytails/protected/extensions/bootstrap'
    ),

 'import'=>array (
    'bootstrap.helpers.TbHtml',

  'components'=>array(
            'bootstrap'=>array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.components.TbApi'
            ),
```

I also added the register function onto protected/views/layouts/main.php

```
<?php /* @var $this Controller */ ?>
<?php Yii::app()->bootstrap->register(); ?>
```

This should work but I keep running into the error:

> Alias "bootstrap.components.TbApi" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.

File is there and readable. I am not sure what could be the issue.

```
[root@unknown000c29a635f6 extensions]# ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxrwx. 10 nobody nobody 4096 Feb  5 01:50 bootstrap

`[root@unknown000c29a635f6 bootstrap]# ls -l
total 112
drwxrwxrwx. 6 nobody nobody  4096 Feb  5 01:50 assets
drwxrwxrwx. 2 nobody nobody  4096 Feb  5 01:50 behaviors
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 nobody nobody   296 Jan 29 14:40 codeception.yml
drwxrwxrwx. 2 nobody nobody  4096 Feb  6 20:29 components
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 nobody nobody  1075 Jan 29 14:40 composer.json
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 nobody nobody 54859 Jan 29 14:40 composer.lock
drwxrwxrwx. 2 nobody nobody  4096 Feb  5 01:50 form
drwxrwxrwx. 3 nobody nobody  4096 Feb  5 01:50 gii
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 nobody nobody   555 Jan 29 14:40 Gruntfile.js
drwxrwxrwx. 2 nobody nobody  4096 Feb  5 01:50 helpers
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 nobody nobody  1521 Jan 29 14:40 LICENSE.txt
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 nobody nobody   604 Jan 29 14:40 package.json
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 nobody nobody   370 Jan 29 14:40 README.md
drwxrwxrwx. 6 nobody nobody  4096 Feb  5 01:50 tests
drwxrwxrwx. 2 nobody nobody  4096 Feb  5 01:50 widgets`
```

Thank you very much for any help you can provide on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. You can fix it configuring all required directories for bootstrap in your main.php:

```
'import'=>array(
    ...
    'bootstrap.helpers.*',
    'bootstrap.widgets.*',
    'bootstrap.behaviors.*',
),
```

Answer (score 1):

With Yiistrap 1.3.0 I had to do the following:

```
'import' => array(
    'bootstrap.helpers.TbHtml',
    'bootstrap.helpers.TbArray',
    'bootstrap.behaviors.TbWidget',
    'bootstrap.widgets.*'
)
```