# Yii using Yiistrap and Yiibooster

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

In my  web application I want to use both Yiibooster and yiistrap together.Yiibooster  alone is working but Yiistrap along with Yiibooster is giving the following error

```
 /extensions/s/bootstrap/helpers/TbArray.php  failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

My code for cpnfig/main.php

```
'aliases' => array(

                'bootstrap' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../extensions/bootstrap'), // change this if necessary
                'yiistrap' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../extensions/yiistrap'),
        ),

'modules'=>array
    (
        'gii'=>array
        (
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'',
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
            'generatorPaths' => array('bootstrap.gii'),
        ),
    ),


'bootstrap' => array
        (
            'class' => 'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap', 


            'responsiveCss'=>true,
        ),
        'Yiistrap' => array
        (
                'class' => 'yiistrap.components.TbApi',


                //'responsiveCss'=>true,
        ),
```

In my extensions folder I have saved as "bootstrap" for yiibooster and "yiistrap" for yiistrap.How should I resolve this? Any body please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following URL:

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/50265-a-guide-for-how-to-integrate-yiibooster-and-yiistrapyiiwheels/

Answer (score 0):

same post is here: [Yiistrap configuration issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641401/yiistrap-config)

you need to add to your config:

```
'import' => array(
    'bootstrap.helpers.TbHtml',
    'bootstrap.helpers.TbArray',
    'bootstrap.behaviors.TbWidget',
    'bootstrap.widgets.*'
)
```